# Creating JSON tree structure based on sql query

Tags: php, sql, json, zend-framework, tree

My simplified tables from database are as follows:
**ImageContainer**

```
Id Name 
=======
1  A  
2  B  
3  C
```

**Images**

```
Id ParentId ImageData  
=====================
1  2        sthsth  
2  1        sthsth  
3  1        sthsth
```

I need to fetch these from database and create tree-like structure (I've got 4 tables of these parent-child relations), then encode it into JSON. I'm using PHP + Zend. So far my solution was to create queries to each table, encode it to JSON and then manually insert child JSON into parent JSON. Is there any better way to do this?

So far I tried

```
private function insertAsLastInJson($json, $name, $insert)
{
    if(strlen($json) < 2)
        return '{' . $insert . '}';
    $in = ",\"$name\":$insert";
    return substr($json, 0, strlen($json) - 1) . $in;
}
```

and then I used it like this:

```
$json = Zend_Json::encode($imageContainerRow); //$imageContainerRow contains single 'ImageContainer' row fetched from database
insertAsLastInJson($json, "images", $imagesRows); //$imagesRows contains multiple 'Images' rows fetched from database and encoded to JSON, separated by commas and everything is in beetween [ ].
```

Example JSON would be:

```
{"Id":1,"Name":"A","Images":[{"Id":2,"ParentId":1,"ImageData":"sthsth"},
{"Id":3,"ParentId":1,"ImageData":"sthsth"}]}
```

This required some parentheses insertions but all in all I got it working. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: well I was fetching records from 'Images' and i used Zend_Json::encode() on them. The same thing for 'ImageContainer' rows. Then i manually inserted according rows into parent Json-string.

Comment: did your solution work? If you want us to improve on your method it would be best to include some code. Alternatively if you want help with something that's gone wrong, it would be best to include some code

Comment: My solution works but it's ugly. I am asking if there's a way to do this properly.

Comment: so... can you include some code so it can be made pretty? You are asking for a solution from scratch which isn't such a nice thing to do. share a little

Comment: Well I hoped that if I use SQL join query, then there may be a way to create JSON-tree structure based on query. I'm preparing my code right now.

Comment: I added some code to my question.

Comment: Why not simply create an ad hoc array of arrays and then ust json_encode on the lot?